# Blazor login page customization

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I customize the view of the default `Register` and `Login` pages in Blazor server-side application?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Right click on your Blazor project and select Add > New Scaffolded Item > Select Identity from the left hand menu and click Add. You can then select the default pages you wish to override and when you’re done they will be scaffolded to your project and you can edit them.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But unfortunately, this scaffolding creates schtml files instead of razor components. And I can't use existing Layouts which are components now. :(

Comment: Unfortunately there isn’t a scaffolding option which creates Razor Components at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I used the technique shown in this post https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13601#issuecomment-679870698 . Source can be downloaded here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/files/5143021/BlazorIdentity.zip

There is s follow-up discussion, if this approach is 100% secure... I am not able to evaluate security in such detail I used this for my project (non banking area). I am in the development phase testing it, but is seems to be working.

There are other projects using ASP net core identity from Blazor pages (not cshtml), where you coudl get inspiration:

- BlazorHero https://github.com/blazorhero/CleanArchitecture
- BlazorBoilerplate https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate